# Can there be a stack exchange for casual, rural bike riding and remote touring free of the fanaticism of professional bike riders?

Tags: touring

No doubt this bike stack exchange is extremely useful for many types of questions and answers.

But I think it is also heavily skewed in perspective against many people who are interested in "quality", casual, rural bike riding and touring remote from metropolitan areas.  I put "quality" in quotes because many people think that means expensive, and that is not what I mean.  Maybe "intelligent" would be a better word in place of "quality".

Anyway, metropolitan areas very definitely have their own special problems about bike riding, and, moreover, I would guess that most bike riders are denizens of metropolitan areas.  So it seems very likely that those facts tend strongly to do an awful lot of skewing on this stack exchange away from the above-described casual, rural bike riding.

I am new to this site, but I have gotten the impression that the highly specialized fanaticism of professional bike riding may also be a factor in the skewing.

So I am wondering if there can be a stack exchange for casual, rural bike riding and remote, perhaps solitary, touring free of the fanaticism of professional bike riders.

That describes the intent.  Of course, users of each type of stack exchange may find the other type of stack exchange to be useful.  And maybe there are some professional bike riders who don't think that every human interaction has to be a zero-sum game devoid of win-win outcomes.  So I don't mean to denigrate professional bike riders generally or even specifically.

But I am wondering it is possible to avoid being steamrolled by hard-nosed city slickers and professional bike riders who generally have very different interests.

It is my impression that voting is likely based on whether a person likes the question or does not like the question, and such things are extremely subjective.  Voting may also be based on what the voter thinks his/her buddies and associates will like or not like and what the current "buzz" is among biking enthusiasts, especially those in metropolitan areas.  So based on sociological network theory about friends and associates in metropolitan areas, this seems to be an extremely strong reason for creating a separate stack exchange for rural, casual bike riding.

But try telling that to a lion who thinks you are a delicious-looking snack.

I tried "alternate-stack-exchange" "rural" and "casual" for tags, but the system does not like them.

Comment: I'm using quite a bite of restraint to avoid writing a novel about how I really don't understand where this is coming from.  You've asked 1 question and already you want to create an entire new site? The simple answer is, the product you're looking for doesn't exist. Remember to lock up your bike and be responsible for your own property. There are plenty of quality locks that will provide very good security.  But you actually have to use them. If you leave your garage open and unlocked, don't be surprised if your bicycle, lawnmower, or various other things go missing.

Comment: I also think it's interesting that you feel we are "professionals"  While I'm sure there are a few people who are racers, the feeling that I get is that a lot of people here (most likely the majority) are quite casual, and really just ride for fun or transportation.

Comment: You've been here a whole two days and you think this forum is dominated by fanatics and pro snobs? I've been here 3 years and have yet to encounter a single person I knew or thought was a professional racer. I'm also yet to encounter fanaticism of any sort, except maybe fanaticism for riding bikes. Questions and answers from casual cyclists all over the place. How you missed them is a mystery.

Comment: I have seen very little on this site to suggest that it's frequented by a large cadre of professional cyclists and mechanics.  However, there are a lot of folks on here with shop experience and deep riding experience from various backgrounds.  The world is not perfect, and many questions don't have a perfect answer or solution.  If we as humans have failed to find a way to solve problems like hunger and clean water, you shouldn't expect first world problems like bike security to have a perfect solution either.

Comment: I have closed this question as off-topic because it is not about bicycles, tricycles, unicycles, handcycles, or their use, as defined as the scope of this site in the [help center](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Question is closed because it should have been on meta.bicycles.stackexhange.com - question is too old to migrate.

Answer (score 6):

The only generalization that holds for the 16k users here is that we like to give and receive advice about cycling.

Many people have their specializations, and some always have something to say. It's like any small community.

As with any community you join, it's a good idea to quietly scout around for a while to get a feel for how the community works before criticizing. Most people have to adjust a bit to fit in to any new community.

Some people can't adjust and move on. If that's you then good luck. If you choose to hang about, then I suggest that you just quietly watch how things work for a while.

Asking good questions actually takes effort (and I haven't mastered that art yet). Answering is much easier. Every now and then you'll see a question where you think can contribute.

Every time you do, you'll learn more about how the place works.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to propose a new site then this is not the place to do it
Propose on http://area51.stackexchange.com/
But I doubt breaking off a casual or any other subset of bicycles is going to go far

Answer (score 2):

I gather from your question that your reasons for wanting a new stack exchange are that you don't like the kind of answers and vote dynamics from this site. I've been told already this is not a forum, well, this is not a forum. They want concrete questions that can have concrete answers, questions should not be duplicated or easily answered on google, etc (read the FAQ). A new stack exchange would have the same dynamics. There are a number of questions on meta stackexchange addressing perceived hostility on all the different stack exchanges. For a newcomer this type of site can easily feel hostile (down votes, deletions, unability to answer from lack of reputation...), try to get the best out of it, and don't bother trying to change the spirit, for more warm environments you can try bikeforums.